# post variables and label fields - UPDATED

Tags: php, forms

I was wondering, If when sending a form via PHP i.e.

```
<label for="adult">Adult:</label>
<input type="radio" value="48" name="type" class="name">
<label for="child">Child:</label>
<input type="radio" value="12" name="type" class="name">    
<label for="oap">OAP:</label>
<input type="radio" value="25" name="type" class="name">
<label for="trial">Trial:</label>
<input type="radio" value="12" name="type" class="name">
```

Is there a way, to not only get the radio's `$_POST` but also it's associated `<label>` value, i.e. `Adult:`, `Child:` or `OAP`?

Thanks

UPDATED:

Ok, so I have now added a 2nd input field, which has the same numeric value as another. This means that I can no longer associte a numberic value, with the label, i.e. if the user has chosen child with a value of 12, i can no longer say `12 = child`, since 12 could also be `trial`. This is my main reason why I'd like to get the label as well.

Thanks

Comment: Not without putting them in hidden fields... why do you need them?

Comment: You could change the value attributes of the radio button controls to include them (ie. "48,Adult", "12,Child") ... why do you have numeric values in the radio buttons if they don't represent the option itself anyway?

Comment: Are you not getting confused with your markup, name="type" on all of your inputs?

Comment: @Decad – That's how you mark up radio groups.

Comment: There is an error in the HTML though — the labels have `for` attributes to associate them with form controls, but none of the radio buttons have a matching `id` attribute.

Comment: my mistake, using the name 'type' confused my sleep deprived brain

Comment: The numeric values are to calculate a value, i.e. a price. The form is to pay for a subscription and the radio's are part of the choices. So I needed the `label` value associated with the radio choice, so I could display the type the user had chosen, i.e `You chose: OAP costing 25`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: untested
You should just have an array of values/labels

```
$radios = array("48" => "Adult", "12=>"child", etc)
```

Then you can get the name based on the value

```
$name = $radios[$_POST['type']];
```

Answer (score 2):

These values are not sent with the post request. Trying to find some sort of documentation to back this up but I can't seem to find anything right now. Basically, those values are not part of the form. What's posted with the form is the value of input elements, select elements, textarea elements, etc but not the text of their containers.

Edit: I don't understand why these fields would have the same value if they aren't the same thing. Maybe they shouldn't be grouped together in the same `name`? If you can't use a different number then how about adding a prefix or suffix to the value like `value="12trial"`.

Essentially, the value of the value can be completely arbitrary. The server should know which value in the post data corresponds to which actual value on the server. It's also important to note that it may not be a good idea to use the actual value being posted from the page as a value in your code. Each value should evaluate to something else with a default in case someone sends a request with incorrect data to your page.

Answer (score 1):

Given that markup, and assuming you don't want to add insane JS, then no, not from the browser.

Since you sent the HTML to the browser in the first place, you should be able to associate '48' with 'Adult' on the server (and so on). Do that.

Comment: Else just straight change the values to 'Adult', 'Child', 'OAP' and de-reference them on the backend. Same thing really associate 'Adult' with '48' etc

Answer (score 0):

You probably could, with some array or sorts, but in all honesty I would argue that the value's should correspond to id's that you can just either look up from a db and show them, or use them to do something like this;

```
<? if ($_POST['type'] == '12') {
       echo('Child');
   } ?>
```

And then just repeat the process.